# Can I use trigger in mysql for use in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I need my php script do something only when my mysql database is: UPDATING or INSERTING.

And I don't know how to do this. Exist any function for do this?
I thought about a solution that was using a trigger in mysql to warn when it was an update or an insert. And with that execute the functions of my php script. Can I do that?

Example:
(In my php script)

```
If ($trigger-> _updating) {
    echo 'Works update';
} elseif ($trigger-> _inserting) {
    echo 'Works insert';
}else{
    echo 'did nothing';
}
```

MORE DETAILS:

I try to do: Make a check when in my mysql database is an update of a table or when you insert new records into the same tables.

What for? For my PHP script, when it was an update or insert, update data in a table in a html page or insert new data has been entered.

Because what I'm doing now is: If you want to update the data in the table (or check if there were updates), I have a button that you do is a SELECT * and then replace the data to the table (something that for me is inefficient because it is very cost)
The same happens with the insertions of new records. I want to improve the code to not do a whole process for nothing.

Comment: Can you please give more details about what you are trying to do? Why do you need a php script as a MySQL trigger?

Comment: @Dvex - Do not make things too complicated. Make it logical. If you are hitting performance problems check that the queries are using indexes, do some profiling and find out where the bottle neck is. It saves you time and effort to do it this way rather than second guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Do not get PHP to do this.

Instead construct the database in such a way that it maintains consistency regardless of the technology that is using it (PHP, C++ or even the command line program MySql). Do this by using constraints and triggers. In this way the data in the database will never get corrupt or invalid.